# PCF Staticfile_buildpack not considering Staticfile

Tags: cloud-foundry

I'm trying to deploy Angular 6 application to PCF using "`cf push -f manifest.yml`" command. 
Deployment works fine, except its not considering options set in "[Staticfiles](https://docs.run.pivotal.io/buildpacks/staticfile/index.html#config-process)" .

To be specific, I've below values in `Staticfile`, to force HTTPS, and to include ".well-known" folder which will be excluded by default due to "." prefix.

```
force_https: true
host_dot_files: true
location_include: .well-known/assetlinks.json
```

I also have a `manifest.yml` file with below values,

```
applications:
- name: MyApp
  instances: 1
  memory: 256M
  instances: 1
  random-route: false
  buildpack: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/staticfile-buildpack.git
  path: ./dist
  routes:
      - route:myapp.example.com
```

Is there an alternate option to set these params in manifest.yml or how to I achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First..

> buildpack: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/staticfile-buildpack.git

Don't do this. You don't want to point to the master branch of a buildpack, it could be unstable. Point to a release, like `https://github.com/cloudfoundry/staticfile-buildpack.git#v1.4.31` or use the system provided staticfile buildpack, like `staticfile_buildpack`.

> To be specific, I've below values in Staticfiles

It's not `Staticfiles`, plural. It's `Staticfile` singular. Make sure you have the correct file name & that it's in the root of your project (i.e. same directory that you're pushing), which is `./dist` based on `path:` in your manifest.

**Update:** For angular, "Staticfile" should be under "src" folder, which will put it under dist on building.

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/staticfile/index.html#config-process

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was having Staticfile(as singular only, it was a typo in my question :) in root of the project and not under "src" folder, which has to be the case to make it come in root of "dist" folder in Angular, which I was using to deploy. Thanks for pointing to it. :)